# Start Activity and don't destroy other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android and started the activities A - B - C - D. From activity D, when I open activity A again then how can I start so that activities B and C don't finish and A starts again? There should only be one activity A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Intent Flag` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

In D

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);
i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

This will simply bring `ActivityA` to the front of the stack and leave `B` and `C` where they are which I believe is what you want. Then you can obviously call `finish()` on D if you want to remove it from the stack.

You can find all available flags in the [Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: There is tabHost Activity. I am at the Activity D when I am trying to start the A from the Tabhostactivity then its not opening.

Comment: Its not opening with the way I suggested? Are you getting any error? Have you made sure the code is being reached?